# How to make a can't hide widget?

Tags: widgets, dashboard

I want make a widget show on my wordpress dashboard and show for other users .

and I want make it always show (can't hiddden by other use ,only can by code).

Is here any one can help me ?

THIS IS MY CODE

```
function example_add_dashboard_widgets() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
        'example_dashboard_widget', // Widget slug.
        'Example Dashboard Widget', // Title.
        'example_dashboard_widget_function' // Display function.
    );
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'example_add_dashboard_widgets');

function example_dashboard_widget_function() {
    echo "Hello World, I'm a great Dashboard Widget";
}
```

Comment: you mean that the users souldn't unselect this widget in the screen options of the dashboard ?

Comment: @mmm yes, i think you are right. do you make it success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to block the ablility to hide it, you can use that :

```
const WIDGET_TO_SHOW = "example_dashboard_widget";


add_filter("get_user_option_metaboxhidden_dashboard", function ($result, $option, $user) {

    $result = array_diff($result, [WIDGET_TO_SHOW]);

    return $result;

}, 10, 3);
```

this is just server side. to be more clear for the user, you can use JavaScript to hide the checkbox in "screen options".